# XML string/array Comparison

Tags: c#

I'm trying to match the indexes from "filename" and "filesize" with the ones from "xml". They contain filesize and names. I need to match them up in an if statment. I'm stuck though, and have no idea how to proceed.

```
    public static void APB()
    {
        ArrayList filename = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList filesize = new ArrayList();
        var directory = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        var files= directory.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        long fnd = 0;
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            filename.Add(file.FullName);
            filesize.Add(fnd += file.Length);
        }

        ArrayList xml = new ArrayList();
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(dictonary.launcher);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    xml.Add(reader.Name);
                    while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
                    xml.Add(reader.Name + "=" + reader.Value);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you are trying to do. Can you post the xml file you are using?
If you are using .Net 2.0 or later, try using collection classes from `System.Collections`, instead of `ArrayList`. If you are using .Net 3.5 or later consider using `System.Xml.Linq.XElement` to parse your xml.

Comment: this snippet is so .NET 1.1; what version are you on?

Comment: Provide more info. You are filling to arraylist with info we can understand. Then you do nothing more with that. You are reading _random_ attributes with values from _random_ xml elements into another arraylist in random text format and don't use that. How the hell are we supposed to know what you mean? APB? (Hint: a snippet of the XML is probably worth a lot)

Answer (score 0):

Create anonymous types for each with the name and size and compare them.

Comment: his is the first few lines.


What I'm actually trying to do is make sure what's in
ArrayList filename = new ArrayList();
ArrayList filesize = new ArrayList();

matches what's in

Comment: ArrayList xml = new ArrayList();


<Patch
Name="Client"
Version="1.5.1.564774">
<File
Filename="APBGame\Baked\DO_NOT_DELETE.TXT"
Size="0"
CRC="0"
DownloadSize="134"
MD5="ea5fed5339d0a56a2891c82488644ae9" />
<File
Filename="APBGame\Config\APBCompat.ini"
Size="62700"
CRC="3658106634"
DownloadSize="8184"
MD5="3dfdcbeb4f8a55b925471d0c0b148cef" />
<File
Filename="APBGame\Config\APBCompat_APBLoginLevel.ini"
Size="2740"
CRC="242915548"
DownloadSize="451"
MD5="560a222ce465e74aff802ddadece375e" />

Comment: It's a rather large file. around 2.5 mb

I'm using .net 4